# Problems in creating certificate with SHA256 / SHA512

Tags: openssl, certificates, hashsum

I want to generate a self-signed certificate with SHA256 or SHA512, but I have problems with it. I have created a script, which should does this automatically:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "WORKSPACE: $WORKSPACE"

SSL_DIR=$(pwd)/httpd_ssl_certs
OPENSSL_CNF=$(pwd)/openssl.cnf

if [ -d "$SSL_DIR" ]; then
        rm -rvf "$SSL_DIR"
fi

mkdir -vp "$SSL_DIR"

pushd "$SSL_DIR"

# check if openssl.cnf exists
if [ ! -f "$OPENSSL_CNF" ]; then
    echo "Could not find $OPENSSL_CNF. Build will be exited."
    exit 1
fi

echo " - create private key"
openssl genrsa -out server.key.template 2048
echo " - create signing request"
openssl req -nodes -new -sha256 -config $OPENSSL_CNF -key server.key.template -out server.csr.template
echo " - create certificate"
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr.template -signkey server.key.template -out server.crt.template -extfile $OPENSSL_CNF
```

And I have a `openssl.cnf` file with configuration for it:

```
[ ca ]
default_ca                      = CA_default

[ CA_default ]
# how long to certify
default_days                    = 365
# how long before next CRL
default_crl_days                = 30
# use public key default MD
default_md                      = sha256

# keep passed DN ordering
preserve                        = no

policy                          = policy_anything

[ policy_anything ]
countryName                     = optional
stateOrProvinceName             = optional
localityName                    = optional
organizationName                = optional
organizationalUnitName          = optional
commonName                      = optional
emailAddress                    = optional

[ req ]
default_bits                    = 2048
default_keyfile                 = server.key.template
distinguished_name              = req_distinguished_name
prompt                          = no
encrypt_key                     = no
# add default_md to [ req ] for creating certificates with SHA256
default_md                      = sha256

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName                     = "AB"
stateOrProvinceName             = "CD"
localityName                    = "Some town"
organizationName                = "XXX Y"
organizationalUnitName          = "XXX Y"
commonName                      = "localhost"
emailAddress                    = "somemail@some.org"
```

When I run the script with this openssl.cnf, then I get a certifiacte, but this certificate is always encrypted with SHA1. I checked it with this command: `openssl x509 -in server.crt.template -text -noout | grep 'Signature`. I always get this output:

```
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
```

Can someone give me a hint, whats false there?

Comment: What is the output of *openssl list-message-digest-algorithms*? Does it contain *RSA-SHA256 => SHA256*?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Yes.

Comment: On Debian and Arch (version 1.0.2j)  I cannot reproduce the problem. You may wish to re-install the *openssl* package.

Answer (score 0):

The following is my pertinent notes on generating, albeit not certificates themselves, a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) with openssl.

The syntax with placeholders looks like this:

> openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -out
>   {DOMAIN.TLD}.rsa.csr -keyout {DOMAIN.TLD}.rsa.pkey -subj
>   "/C={US}/ST={STATE||PROVENCE}/L={CITY}/O={COMPANY-NAME}/CN={DOMAIN.TLD}"

This is the exact command I used to generate my own CSR, which I give to my SSL certificate provider.

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:4096 -sha256 -nodes -out rustbeltrebellion.com.csr -keyout rustbeltrebellion.rsa.pkey -subj "/C=US/ST=OHIO/L=EASTLAKE/O=RUSTBELTREBELLION/CN=RUSTBELTREBELLION.COM"
```

The benefit of a CSR is that your private key stays more private. I am aware of only two ways to create a certificate-- by running your private key through the openssl library or your CSR through the openssl library. Both give you a functionally identical certificate when the dust settles. One allows your private key to remain private (the CSR does that).

Comment: Yeah, it is likely that the poster has either has solved the problem already or of course the only possible alternative is that kristian died. Anyway, this is for anyone that stumbles on it later.